# Ubuntu installaion doesn't ask for boot loader

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I was installing Ubuntu on a system in my office and I was surprised by how user friendly it is. While the process was smooth as butter, it never really asked me about installing a boot loader.

I will probably, grab a Linux rescue disk and install grub when I find time, but It seemed strange to me.

The machine previously was running windows 7 and it had two partitions (one was around 900 gigs and the other was close to a 100 megs) I chose to resize the windows partition and install ubuntu.

Anyone ran into the same problem?

Comment: No, but I don't see this as a problem. It probably asked you which disc to use and if you use the whole disc it just install the bootloader as well. If not update your answer with how you selected your installation partition(s). And leave out the Thanks, they are inappropriate.

Comment: Sure. I have update the question accordingly.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and which install method / image did you use? What options did you choose during the install? If the system installed and boots successfully it's not really a problem, is it?

Comment: There weren't many options to choose form. It asked me if I wanted to have both windows/linux on the machine and I said went with that. After that I had to resize the windows partition.

After that it went ahead with installing. I know that ubuntu is installed but without the bootloader its not of use isn't it?

Comment: AFAIR unless you select “advanced installation” or some such Ubuntu installs its bootloader silently, either in UEFI or in the boot sector depending on the existing setup. What happens now when you boot? If the installer set up your system in a way that doesn't boot, report a bug against the Ubuntu installer, providing as much information as you can about your setup.

Comment: Make sense. It was UEFI bios and legacy boot was enabled on the machine. Will take a look once I get access to the machine.